# Github Action to restrict merge to Admins only

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to restrict the ability to merge PR to Admins only by using GitHub action. Below is my `mergepr.yml`

`name: Restrict merges to admins

on:
pull_request:
branches:
- dev
- master

jobs:
restrict-merges:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Install GitHub CLI
    run: |
      # Download the GitHub CLI binary for Linux (replace URL with the correct one)
      curl -fsSL https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/download/v2.35.0/gh_2.35.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz -o gh.tar.gz
      tar -xzf gh.tar.gz
      sudo mv gh_* /usr/local/bin/gh
      gh --version
  - name: Set up GitHub CLI
    run: |
      echo "Setting up GitHub CLI"
      gh config set -h github.com ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
  - name: Check if the user is an admin
    run: |
      PR_NUMBER="${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"
      USER_ROLE=$(gh api users/me/role --jq '.role')
      if [[ $USER_ROLE != '"admin"' ]]; then
        echo "Only admins can merge pull requests into the main branch."
        exit 1
      fi
  - name: Merge the pull request
    run: |
      PR_NUMBER="${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"
      gh pr merge $PR_NUMBER --auto
```

`

It was expected for this GitHub action to pass when user is admin, but it fails irrespective of user role.
Below is the error log:

`Run echo "Setting up GitHub CLI" echo "Setting up GitHub CLI" gh config set -h github.com ${GITHUB_TOKEN} shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Setting up GitHub CLI accepts 2 arg(s), received 0 Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `${GITHUB_TOKEN}` that way. Either use `${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}` or pass it as an environment variable (safer).

On top of that, `gh config set -h {host}` expects 2 parameters: `key` and `value`, you are supplying the `{host}` and the `value`, but not the `key`.

```yaml
  - name: Set up GitHub CLI
    run: |
      echo "Setting up GitHub CLI"
      gh config set -h github.com <SOMEKEY> $GITHUB_TOKEN
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

or

```yaml
  # ⚠️ Warning inlining variables and secrets may open you up to 
  #    script intecjtion attacks.

  - name: Set up GitHub CLI
    run: |
      echo "Setting up GitHub CLI"
      gh config set -h github.com <SOMEKEY> ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But you shouldn't have to set the token in the config. [`gh` will automatically pick up the token when you set it in the environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows). Just add the following to the tasks below that need the token to authenticate.

```
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Be sure to read up on [GitHub Actions hardening - script injection attacks](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

Comment: Tried the first way you suggested. But it seems setting the github cli is still encountering some issue. Below is the error log:
`Run echo "Setting up GitHub CLI"
  echo "Setting up GitHub CLI"
  gh config set -h github.com $TOKEN
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    TOKEN: ***
Setting up GitHub CLI
accepts 2 arg(s), received 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`
@jessehouwing